# MVC 3 Razor View Engine Formatting

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

The following piece of code works correctly:

```
<span class="dysiChannelSubscription">
@if (Model.ChannelName == "ninacopes")
{
    <iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="width:200px; height:20px;"
      src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets/follow_button.html?show_count=false&screen_name=@Model.ChannelName">
    </iframe>
}
</span>
```

However, if I change the if to:

```
@if (Model.ChannelType == Fluent.Data.Enums.ChannelTypeEnum.Twitter)
```

It doesn't render any longer.
This is in a partial view.

jQuery yields:

> syntax error
>   `<!DOCTYPE html>`

I have no clue why. Model.ChannelType is of that type, and I get the twitter value purely from intellisense, which makes me wonder why this breaks at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both sides are strings then you can try .ToString() like below.

```
  @if (Model.ChannelType == Fluent.Data.Enums.ChannelTypeEnum.Twitter.ToString())
```

If both Sides are Integer then you can try

```
  @if (Model.ChannelType == (int)Fluent.Data.Enums.ChannelTypeEnum.Twitter)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to compare the type of  the model? Should it not then be something like: `TypeOf(Model.ChannelType)` ?

Comment: what? `ChannelType` is an enum, of type `ChannelTypeEnum`